# How to select the specific class in cifar-10

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to know how to select the specific class in cifar-10. For example, I want 7, "horse" class in cifar-10. And I wrote the below code. But the obtained data is not what I want because it's wrong shape.

Please enlighten me on the specifics.

```py
from keras.datasets import cifar10

(X_train, Y_train), (X_test, Y_test) = cifar10.load_data()

print('X_train shape: {0}, Y_train shape: {1}'.format(X_train.shape, Y_train.shape))
```

```
X_train shape: (50000, 32, 32, 3), Y_train shape: (50000, 1)
```

The below code is wrong.

```py
import numpy as np

filter = np.where(Y_train == 7)

X_train = X_train[filter]
Y_train = Y_train[filter]

print('X_train shape: {0}, Y_train shape: {1}'.format(X_train.shape, Y_train.shape))
```

```
X_train shape: (5000, 32, 3), Y_train shape: (5000,)
```

The expected output is below

```
X_train shape: (5000, 32, 32, 3), Y_train shape: (5000,)
```

Answer (score 1):

For the slicing, do something like:

```
X_train = X_train[filter[0], ...]
Y_train = Y_train[filter[0], ...]
```

And the shapes would be

```
X_train shape: (5000, 32, 32, 3), Y_train shape: (5000, 1)
```